# Unable to setup images from JSON?

Tags: ios, json, swift, firebase-realtime-database, uiimageview

I'm using Firebase Database & Firebase Storage. I have an iOS Swift app, that allows the user to select multiple images, upload them to Firebase Storage, after the upload, it gets the downloaded URLs and stores them like:

[image]

In order to display those images in the app, I have the following `xib` file:

[image]

Where the middle (big) `UIImageView` is inside of a `UIStackView` because it could display more than 1 image.

My problem is that I get the URLs from the database, but for some reason I'm not able to display them in the app. I use the framework `SDWebImage` for caching and displaying images. So far in the app, it worked fine, but not here. I don't get where I'm wrong.

```
    if let photoURLString = post?.photoURLs
    {
        for photo in photoURLString
        {
            let photoURL = URL(string: photo)
            print(photoURL!)
            postImage.sd_setImage(with: photoURL)
            //postImagesStackView.addArrangedSubview(postImage)
        }
    }
```

`post` is the model object. I'm using `for in` to loop through the array of images from the database. When I print each url, I get the actual URL. But it's simple not displayed. I get this. The images are nowhere to be found/displayed:

[image]

Comment: Did you add constraints for UIImageView?

Comment: The `UIStackView` that the `UIImageView` is placed in has constraints. The `UIImageView` itself doesnt have constraints

Comment: Use view debugging in Xcode to check if your view has proper bounds at runtime you could also add a background colour to check if it has proper bounds.

Comment: try to set an image from a png/jpg file in your app and then check if it is visible or not. If not, this could be due to wrong constraints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add aspect ratio for UIImage. Ex: In xib file, set ratio of UIImage to 1.

Comment: Ah! This actually solved half of the issue. With posts (`UITableViewCells`) that contain just a single image, it works. It shows the display images, BUT with posts that have multiple image, it displays none. I thought that `postImagesStackView.addArrangedSubview(postImage)` will solve that, but it didn't. The `postImagesStackView` is an `IBOutlet` of the `UIStackView` that the images are placed in. Any idea how to solve that?

Comment: After using `postImagesStackView.addArrangedSubview(postImage)` to add new image, did you set ratio constraint for `postImage`?

Comment: I set it prior to that, in the `xib` file itself. They all use the same `xib`

Comment: Your word `multiple image` means that a cell has multiple UIImageView or just one UIImageView and multiple UIImage ?

Comment: No. It means that it has 1 `UIImageView` in the `xib` but it needs to display 1 or more images (depends on the corresponding number images from the database for each post). I asked some other developers and they said that the only dynamic way to display more than one image in a cell that is to add them in a stackview. So, if a post has 4 images, the cell should display 4 images in that stackview by using `addArrangedSubview(uiview)` method. If it has 1 image, it should display just that one single image. I hope this makes sense

Comment: I think you don't need any `UIImageView` in xib file and just add `UIImageView` depend on the corresponding number images. I have tried to use `addArrangedSubview` and it work but you need creating a new `UIImageView` for each image you want to add to cell. After creating `UIImageView` give it ratio constraint. One more, make sure your cell has dynamic height for scaling when we have more image from response.

Comment: Can you please update your answer with the code that you've tested?